# Why ajax refreshes my page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

[My code](https://codepen.io/spacepirate/full/VaRWRv/)

```
function getQuote(){
$.ajax({
    headers: {

        "X-Mashape-Key": "......",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Accept: "application/json"
    },
    url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
    success: function(response) {
        var r = JSON.parse(response);
        currentQuote = r.quote;
        currentAuthor = r.author;
}
```

There might be some syntax error above but that's because of editing the code here. So there's no syntax error in my original code.

I simply want to change the content of the quote text and writer when the button is clicked without the page being refreshed.

Comment: Maybe it's not Ajax refreshing, but something in the click handler that also makes the Ajax call.  If you post that code, it would be helpful

Comment: Thank you Michael I found out the problem, if you look into the codepen, it was the href attribute of the button, it was first href='' and now I changed it to href='#' and the problem is solved, although I don't know why exactly!